# ListView SelectedItem binding not working

Tags: listview, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I'm using a custom `LabelRenderer` for my Xamarin forms project in Android.
Inside of this `LabelRenderer` I'm using `Control.SetTextIsSelectable(true)` so that people can copy / paste the text from the given label. ( this method is available on Android internal `TextView` )

This all works, but by using this inside a `ListView.ItemTemplate` ( just a `StackLayout` with some labels ), the `ListView.SelectedItem` will no longer work.
To be correct, it will work, if you manage to tap outside the boundaries of the labels inside the ItemTemplate. So the touch event for the SelectedItem binding is being eaten by the label, because it needs to look for tap selection to enable the copy / paste feature :/

So in other words, how can we disable the touch behavior of the labels when they are used in a `ListView` in a generic way?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the property `InputTransparent` of your label to true. This way, touch events are ignored on the label and caught by its parent.

UPDATE
If `InputTransparent` doesn't work for you then try `ListViewItemTappedAttached` from
https://github.com/XAM-Consulting/FreshEssentials

Example in your page:

```
yourList.SetBinding<IYourPageViewModel>(ListViewItemTappedAttached.CommandProperty, x => x.YourCommand);
```

and in your view model:

```
YourCommand = new Command<IYourCellViewModel>(item => yourMethod(item));
```

Comment: Sorry should have mentioned that I already tried that and still event won't go through to the SelectedItem